# RDP to Azure VMs through public IP versus VPN

Tags: vpn, rdp, azure

I have two options for remoting into our Azure VMs: RDP to public IP or RDP through VPN.

I'm certain using a VPN is 'more' secure. But my question is: Is it still reasonably secure to have a hole in the firewall for our local office's IP and RDP directly w/o VPN?

It's just way, way more convenient to be able to just double click an RDP icon and not have to turn off another VPN I already have to use for another hosting environment so that I can turn on the Azure VPN every time I want to log on to an Azure VM. But I also don't want to be doing something that's stupidly insecure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**VPN with 2FA authentication is the way to go.**

First of all you can't do 2FA with RDP, meaning you increase security risk significantly.

RDP has had several vulnerabilities, a few of the most recent 'BlueKeep' CVE-2019-1181, CVE-2019-1182, CVE-2019-0708.

This is the scenario where convenience shouldn't win.

Comment: There's not really a question of whether I will be using RDP. Any suggestion that I don't use RDP is a nonstarter. It's just a question of whether doing it without a VPN over a hole in the firewall that is restricted to incoming requests from the IP of my local office is unreasonably unsafe as compared to doing it over VPN.

Comment: Though maybe you are simply implying that because of RDP's insecurities, I should use a VPN. If that's the case, I would be more interested in knowing why access to public IP that will only listen to requests from my IP is particularly unsafe if you have anything to say about that.

Comment: Or if you were suggesting to not use RDP at all, then that's literally like saying I should quit doing my job because there is no feasible way I complete the tasks I need to do without it. That is, there may exist ways to do each individual task I do without RDP, but I would literally be spending all my time learning how to do that rather than actually doing my job.

Comment: @BVernon having the rdp as less publicly exposed creates less risk. Why not just setup site to site VPN with your Azure infrastructure? It will essentially be the same from a usability perspective, but you will avoid potential configuration mistakes.

Comment: @BVernon no pun intended here, but RDP was actually never intended for system management in the first place :). That being said I use it as well for most non-automated tasks.

Comment: Good question... never used site to site before. I will look into it, thanks. As for rdp not being intended for management, I think you could equally say that airplanes were not intended to be used as war machines in the beginning either. But here we are :)

Comment: Although technically I still don't have an answer to my question. I said myself from the beginning I was certain using a VPN was more secure. So suppose someone can easily hack RDP... how easy is it for them to get a request past the firewall without physically being in my office? They would have to know what ip the router is allowing and they'd have to trick the router into thinking the request was coming from that ip right? Is that simple to do?

Comment: Also I just looked up the vulnerabilities you mentioned. As far as I can tell we know about these only because Microsoft told us after they fixed them, and they weren't aware of any exploitations. But these issues were found during efforts to harden the software. That actually gives me some level nof confidence that rdp IS secure now, for better or worse.